# Multiple VideoViews with one MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm wondering if its possible to attach multiple VideoViews to one MediaPlayer so all VideoViews play the same video?

I've looked through the sources of VideoView, MediaPlayer, MediaController etc, and I think it should work with some kind of "composite"-VideoView that holds references to the other VideoViews and delegates the video to them?!

Has anybody ever been done something like this before and can give me some advice if its possible at all?